# JSCIPOpt set objective

Tags: java, scip

I am trying to use JSCIPOpt to solve a maximization problem but I couldn't find a way to set the problem objective. The scip document says

> The default objective sense for SCIP problems is minimizing. Since we have a
>   maximization problem we have to change this:
>   SCIP_CALL_EXC(SCIPsetObjsense(scip, SCIP_OBJSENSE_MAXIMIZE));

But I was not able to find any API call in the JSCIPOpt to set objective. I was, however, able to find **setMaximize** in PySCIPOpt. Am I missing something? What is the correct way to set the objective using JSCIPOpt?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be supported yet. You should just create an issue on the github page and submit a feature request: https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/JSCIPOpt

Even better, though: Implement the feature yourself (see https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/JSCIPOpt#how-to-extend-the-interface) by introducing the necessary interface function in the same way it's done in PySCIPOpt and submit a merge request! This way you learn something on the way and everyone's happy :-)